# Unable to select item in spark.components.List after de-selection

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have a spark List defined as:

```
<s:List id="symbolList"  dataProvider="{symbolListCollection}" change="symbolNameChangeHandler(event)"></s:List>
```

With the change handler defined like this:

```
protected function symbolNameChangeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
   symbolList.validateProperties();
   changeSymbolView(symbolList.selectedItem);
}
```

and symbolListCollection as an ArrayList filled with Strings.

At first, the change event works fine, and I get what I expect.

However, if I Ctrl-click on the selected item, to de-select it, i am unable to ever select an item again.

When I click on something to try to select it, the change event DOES fire, however, the ItemChangeEvent has both oldIndex and newIndex set to -1

Any idea what I might have done to cause this, or what I can do to remedy it?

Comment: Show a runnable sample to demo your problem.  I'm confused as to what the issue is.  If you control click to deselect something, then nothing is selected and on the next click I would expect the index to be -1.

Comment: Yeah, I would expect oldIndex to be -1 and newIndex to be whatever it's supposed to be.  I'll see if I can throw together a runnable demo.  Also, I just threw some more details up in case they help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found my own issue.

In the method changeSymbolView(), I had the following line:

```
if(selectedItem == null) {
   symbolList.selectedItem = null;
}
```

Somehow, this line prevented it from ever being selectable again.  Removing it caused it to work as expected.